# unable to open url of same domain by launchUrl due to reason it is consumed as incoming link by unilinks flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () => launchUrl(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://${other_domain}"
        ),
    ),
    child: Text(
        "some website",
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textScaleFactor: 0.6,   
        ),
     ),
)
```

The above code works for different domains, where as for the domain which is registered as andriod:host in unilinks, unable open by launchurl for below example. I found the reason because the uri is consumed as incoming uri by unilinks handler

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () => launchUrl(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://${same_domain}/privacy_policy.html"
        ),
    ),
    child: Text(
        "privacy policy",
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textScaleFactor: 0.6,   
        ),
     ),
)
```

Any workaround / solution?